# How to do I work on different version of application when using Git / BitBucket?

Tags: c#, git, git-branch, bitbucket

Need some advice again please.

This is regarding a single developer shop. I have a created a small application in C# and I am hosting the code on BitBucket as a Git Repository. The application is a WinForm app and version 1.0 is ready to be released. I have all my source code uploaded to BitBucket. During testing, number of bugs have been discovered and I have received couple of minor enhancement requests.

My question(s) are: 
1. How do I work on version 1.1?
2. Do I need to create a branch or do I just continue working on the v1.0, making changing as needed? And once v1.1 is ready, then build it and publish it?

Currently, I do not foresee a scenario where I would need to support number of versions. However, I would like some input on the best way to proceed besides making number of folders labeled "My App v1.0", "My App v1.1", etc. :P

Thank you for your help and I am sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches are cheap to make so you should be creating branches all the time in git.  You could create a '`1.1_wip`' branch, and create a branch for each new feature or bug fix you want to work on.  Anytime you finish work in any of your feature or bug fix branches, you merge it into the `1.1_wip` branch.

Once you are ready to release/publish, then you merge your `1.1_wip` branch back into your `master` branch and can create a tag, ex:

```
git checkout master
git merge 1.1_wip
git tag 1.1
```

Comment: I thought branches are more appropriate in a team dev environments. What would branches buy me?

Comment: One example is if you are working on a multiple features simultaneously.  Maybe you are halfway completed with a feature when suddenly it is no longer needed or it should be scrapped.  If you are working with each feature in its own branch, you can safely scrap the 'no longer needed feature' branch and your other branches will be unaffected.  If you were working with all your features in the same branch (ex: `master`), then depending on how intertwined the 'no longer need feature' code is, you'd have to go through manually in your code to remove it.

Comment: Holy crap! That's exactly what I have been doing. I am beginning to like branches already. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You want to use git tags. There's a guide here: http://progit.org/book/ch2-10.html

Create your 1.0 tag when you do your release. Then any development goes on, when you're ready to release 1.1 you create a tag for that versions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought that leaving comments was the same thing as tags. Guess not. lol

Answer (score 1):

It may be slight overkill for your single-developer environment, but, in general, I think this article will give you some ideas about how to structure your repo best for supporting multiple releases with concurrent development and fixes:

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Not that you need to follow this model exactly - you can find what works best for you. But definitely take advantage of branches and tags - branching is super cheap and easy in Git, and it allows you to experiment with new features and/or isolate bugs. Once you start getting used to using branches, you'll find it'll change how you think/develop altogether.

Comment: I will look into that article. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate branch for the development of version 1.1. When it is finished, I'd merge it back into the master branch for the release of 1.1.

Comment: I thought branches are more appropriate in a team dev environments. What would branches buy me?

Comment: Branches would allow you to do a 1.0.1 release with a security fix, independent of anything in your 1.1 branch.

Comment: Makes sense. Guess I need to look into that. Thanks for your help.